# React not being able to acess a query value

Tags: json, reactjs

Hey i am trying to access whats inside of a fetch trought item.name and so on..
I would like to know why i am not being able to access the item properties

However i am not getting anythign back in the return statement, this is the json i need to access.
`{"message":{"_id":"5ea9c860ea9fb600178ae676","name":"frutology","description":"frutas"}}`

```html
import React, {useState,useEffect} from 'react';




function StoreDetails ({ match }) {
    useEffect(()=>{
        fetchItem();

    },[]);
    const[item,setItem]=useState({name: "", description : ""});

    const fetchItem = async() => {
        const fetchItem = await fetch(
            `/storedisplay/${match.params.id}`
        );


        const item = await fetchItem.json();
        setItem(item);
        console.log(item);
    }





    return (

        <div>
            <h1>{item.name}</h1>
            <h2> {item.description}</h2>
        </div>


    );

}


export default StoreDetails;
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that `useState` is asynchronous.

Use `useEffect`.

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(item);
}, [item])
```

Comment: Hmm didnt know that, so after checking my item object is empty..

Comment: I still cant figure out why i cant access the properties inside the return()